# Python Requests getting 401 error

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests

Currently trying to request a json using python but I keep getting a 401 error on response. When I use curl I receive the correct json data.

Curl I use:

```
curl -H "X-Samanage-Authorization: Bearer API_TOKEN" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.samanage.v2.1+json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X GET https://api.samanage.com/incidents.json
```

Python that results in 401 error:

```
import json
import requests

response  = requests.get('https://api.samanage.com/incidents.json', headers={'X-Samanage-Authorization': 'API_TOKEN'})

print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Could you please try with  `headers={'X-Samanage-Authorization': 'Bearer API_TOKEN'}`

Comment: Apart from the above comment: the `curl` command you used is not the same as what you did in your python code. Does `curl -H "X-Samanage-Authorization: Bearer API_TOKEN" -X GET https://api.samanage.com/incidents.json` return the correct result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to do, your problem is probably that you are not [**specifying the type of your credentials**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re).

Try doing :

```
import json
import requests

response  = requests.get('https://api.samanage.com/incidents.json', headers={'X-Samanage-Authorization': 'Bearer ' + API_TOKEN})

print(response.status_code)
```

Another case, your `API_TOKEN` is not the actual token if you have not made a mistake while typing your code back. You have a STRING `API_TOKEN`, but not the actual token.

Comment: Perfect, was missing the Bearer in the header. I ended up using response  = requests.get('https://api.samanage.com/incidents.json', headers={'X-Samanage-Authorization': 'Bearer API_TOKEN'}) which worked! Thanks for your help